# how to add a slash item before alias of a page

Tags: administrator, url, alias

Right now, https://www.co.bergen.nj.us/shopping is a page on my site

I want to make that page https://www.co.bergen.nj.us/tourism/shopping but I do not know how to add that to the URL.  I tried modifying the menu item's alias to be "tourism/shopping" but the site converts it to "tourism-shopping" when I save the changes.  How do I add "/tourism/" to the URL before the alias? (ie edit before the alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok this is kind of an answer to my question but not the one I was looking for because it has limitations that I do not want.

If you have a menu that links to the page then clicking on that menu item will bring you to `www.website.com/menutitle/pagealias`.  This method may be useful for someone else in the future but it is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

its based on your menu structure isnt it?
so to get this struct you need to add a menu entry for tourism and put there the item shopping as child.

maybe there exists an alternative but i would try that.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not do it, the page 'Services' (whose name I just changed to 'Attractions' is already in the 'Tourism' menu but the url does not reflect that.  Any other ideas?